# Migrating in-house authentication to ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm working on upgrading a *very* old website from classic ASP to ASP.NET Core. Part of this is to migrate the users (whose passwords are stored in plaintext, naturally) into Identity. We're using a unit test project to handle the migration, but that project can't access Identity, understandably.

What's the best option here? The main issue I see is getting passwords into the correct format, but I think I could look at the source of ASP.NET Identity and mimic the functionality to properly hash everything in the migration. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Hash algorithm used by ASP.NET Identity 3 is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L94). However, it is not *easy* to run outside of ASP.NET Idetity, unless you copy its dependents to your project.

[HashPasswordV3](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L139)

```
private static byte[] HashPasswordV3(string password, 
   RandomNumberGenerator rng, KeyDerivationPrf prf, 
   int iterCount, int saltSize, int numBytesRequested)
    {
    // Produce a version 3 (see comment above) text hash.
    byte[] salt = new byte[saltSize];
    rng.GetBytes(salt);
    byte[] subkey = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password, salt, prf, iterCount, numBytesRequested);

    var outputBytes = new byte[13 + salt.Length + subkey.Length];
    outputBytes[0] = 0x01; // format marker
    WriteNetworkByteOrder(outputBytes, 1, (uint)prf);
    WriteNetworkByteOrder(outputBytes, 5, (uint)iterCount);
    WriteNetworkByteOrder(outputBytes, 9, (uint)saltSize);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 13, salt.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 13 + saltSize, subkey.Length);
    return outputBytes;
}
```

[VerifyHashedPasswordV3](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/PasswordHasher.cs#L248)

```
private static bool VerifyHashedPasswordV3(byte[] hashedPassword, string password, out int iterCount)
{
    iterCount = default(int);

    try
    {
        // Read header information
        KeyDerivationPrf prf = (KeyDerivationPrf)ReadNetworkByteOrder(hashedPassword, 1);
        iterCount = (int)ReadNetworkByteOrder(hashedPassword, 5);
        int saltLength = (int)ReadNetworkByteOrder(hashedPassword, 9);

        // Read the salt: must be >= 128 bits
        if (saltLength < 128 / 8)
        {
            return false;
        }
        byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(hashedPassword, 13, salt, 0, salt.Length);

        // Read the subkey (the rest of the payload): must be >= 128 bits
        int subkeyLength = hashedPassword.Length - 13 - salt.Length;
        if (subkeyLength < 128 / 8)
        {
            return false;
        }
        byte[] expectedSubkey = new byte[subkeyLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(hashedPassword, 13 + salt.Length, expectedSubkey, 0, expectedSubkey.Length);

        // Hash the incoming password and verify it
        byte[] actualSubkey = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(password, salt, prf, iterCount, subkeyLength);
        return ByteArraysEqual(actualSubkey, expectedSubkey);
    }
    catch
    {
        // This should never occur except in the case of a malformed payload, where
        // we might go off the end of the array. Regardless, a malformed payload
        // implies verification failed.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The passwords are in plain text so you can simply load each user from the current database and add them to the new database using the `UserManager` class in Identity.

The `UserManager` class has a `CreateAsync` method that takes a password and it will handle the hashing for you.

Example:

```
var user = new IdentityUser // or whatever your user class is
{
    UserName = userName,
    Email = email,
    // set other required properties
};

var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

I would recommend manually running this in a separate program as a one-time task.  You won't want this procedure to live in the new app.